# how to add photo

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have a simple model, witch is used as a form .

```
class Test(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True, db_index=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    details = models.TextField()
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.image.name
```

I would like to add the following class Album as a foreign key to Test :

```
class Album(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    public = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

class Tag(models.Model):
    tag = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.tag

class Image(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=60, blank=True, null=True)
    image = models.FileField(upload_to="images/")
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, blank=True)
    albums = models.ManyToManyField(Album, blank=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    rating = models.IntegerField(default=50)
    width = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    height = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.image.name
```

Questions:

1. How to add class Album as a foreigh key to class Test?
2. How to put this relation on the form? - e.g. user is selecting multiple images for uploads wich results in unique Album related to Test class.

Comment: What is the purpose of the Test model?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this for the foreign-key

```
class Test(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True, db_index=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    details = models.TextField()
    album = models.ForeignKey(Album, null=True, blank=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

Comment: Yeap, but the second question remains :)
2. How to put this relation on the form? - e.g. user is selecting multiple images for uploads wich results in unique Album related to Test class.

Comment: You use a inline formset: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formsets

Comment: @Chris Pratt
I can not make it work. The idea is quite simple. I want to have a two models related with foreign key. I've managed to follow the given example but its not really what i've expected)
I want user to fill some data for Test and for Album as well but after all Test and Album instance should be join-ed in database.

maybe its possible to create inlineformset_factory with two forms.ModelForm ?